# for....next loop failed after repeat userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using for next loop with while wend loop inside of it. the problem is when I enter first data and then I want to repeat inserting by choosing vbYes,the loop will repeat but it set the value to i=32 again and proceed while loop eventhough the while{condition} is false.let me give some example,

comboBox1.value = {a,b,c,d}

i={32,33,34,35} ~> i is set to row number.

for the first count,I insert c to combobox1 giving combobox1.value=c and cells(34,2).value=c hence while loop proceed. but when I choose to continue inserting data for second time, it go back to for next loop again but it set the value of i=32, giving cells(32,2).value=c and then proceed to while loop but the while loop suppose to not proceed because the correct value for cells(32,2).value=a . can anyone help?

```
Dim i As Long
Dim prod As String
Dim RowNo As Long
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
Dim sh2 As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


prod = ComboBox1.Value

For i = 32 To 35

  While ComboBox1.Value = Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value

    Rows(i).Select
    Selection.Insert shift = xlDown

    With Worksheets("Input")
    '~insert data
    .Range("B" & i) = ComboBox1.Text
    .Range("C" & i) = TextBox1.Text
    .Range("D" & i) = TextBox2.Text
    .Range("E" & i) = TextBox3.Text
    .Range("F" & i) = TextBox4.Text
    .Range("G" & i) = TextBox5.Text
    .Range("H" & i) = ComboBox2.Text
    .Range("I" & i) = TextBox6.Text
    .Range("J" & i) = TextBox7.Text
    .Range("K" & i) = TextBox8.Text

    End With

    Workbooks(prod & " Input.xlsm").Activate

    '~select row number from another worksheet
    RowNo = Workbooks(prod & " Input.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(31, 3).Value

   Set sh1 = Workbooks(prod & " Input.xlsm").Worksheets("Input")
   Set sh2 = Workbooks("MasterInput.xlsm").Worksheets("Input")

 '~copy inserted data from master input to product input
   sh1.Range(sh1.Cells(RowNo, 2), sh1.Cells(RowNo, 11)).Value = sh2.Range(sh2.Cells((i, 2), sh2.Cells(i , 11)).Value

    If MsgBox("One record written to Master Input. Do you want to continue entering data?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
       GoTo repeat1:

        Else
          Unload Me
    End If

    Exit Sub
  Wend
Next

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
repeat1:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastly! just a simple one line command that i forgot to put.

insert above for loop

```
Workbooks("MasterInput.xlsm").Activate
For i = 32 To 35
```

works now! the i value taken from the second workbook where it suppose to take from first workbook.

Answer (score 0):

You are unloading form from memory.Unload the form when you dont want to continue..

if msgbox("you want to continue",vbyesNo)=vbyes then

```
 goto repeat1
```

else

```
 unload me
```

end if

Comment: thanks but my first version of question is not what i actually need.i've update the question for better understanding..can u please try to look at it again?